# Hibernate: Persisting @OneToMany Stuck with no exception (where child entity insert is not getting printed in showsql)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, persist

Entity Main:

```
 CustomerAgreement {

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerAgreement", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
     private List<CustomerAgreementPeriod> agreementPeriods;
 }
```

Entity where ManyToOne is referred:

```
public class CustomerAgreementPeriod  implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CustomerAgreementPeriodSeq", sequenceName = "CUST_AGT_PERIOD_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "CustomerAgreementPeriodSeq")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTID")
    private CustomerAgreement customerAgreement;
   .
  .
 }
```

Main Code:

```
CustomerAgreement cAgreement = new CustomerAgreement();
        cAgreement.setId(32121212l);
        cAgreement.setName("Kiki");;
        cAgreement.setCustomerId("140");

        List<CustomerAgreementPeriod> cap = new ArrayList<>();
        CustomerAgreementPeriod capy = new CustomerAgreementPeriod();
        capy.setPid("1");
        capy.setValidFrom(new Date());
        capy.setValidTo(new Date());
        capy.setCustomerAgreement(cAgreement);

        CustomerAgreementPeriod capy2 = new CustomerAgreementPeriod();
        capy2.setPid("2");
        capy2.setValidFrom(new Date());
        capy2.setValidTo(new Date());
        capy2.setCustomerAgreement(cAgreement);

        cap.add(capy);
        cap.add(capy2);
        cAgreement.setAgreementPeriods(cap);
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(cAgreement);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Error:

No error is shown but only one insert query to main is shown as below:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        CUST_AGT_PERIOD_SEQ.nextval 
    from
        dual
Hibernate: 
    select
        CUST_AGT_PERIOD_SEQ.nextval 
    from
        dual
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        CIM_SNOW_CUST_AGREEMENT_TAB
    values
```

It appears thread stuck somewhere may be infinite loop or something.

Could any one suggest why this is happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was on my side.

But this is strange that Hibernate does not throw any exception and keep on running.

**Issue**: The field ID and CUSTID do not exists in table as per above mentioned entities.

I think we should always add validate proeprty in persistance.xml to validate at deployment